# JQuery .data() not working?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Recently I was coding away, and I ran into a weird issue.  I was attempting to assign a data attribute to a new element I had created (via jQuery), only to discover it wouldn't actually assign the attribute.    See the link below for an example, the code is listed below:

http://jsfiddle.net/y95p100c/1/

Any idea why this is happening?  I've never stumbled into this...

```
var div = $("<div />")
$(div).data("foo", "bar")
console.log($(div)[0].outerHTML) // prints <div></div>
```

Comment: jQuery's `.data()` function stores values internally.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`data` doesn't *set* `data-*` attributes. It manages a data cache unrelated to `data-*` attributes. It *initializes* from `data-*` attributes if there are any present, but never writes to them. To write to an attribute, use `attr`.

Example: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y95p100c/2/)

```
var div = $("<div />")
$(div).attr("data-foo", "bar")
console.log($(div)[0].outerHTML)
```

What you're seeing is just one of the many ways this can be surprising. Another is that if your markup is `<div id="elm" data-foo="bar"></div>` and at some point you use `$("#elm").data("foo")` to get the value (and it will indeed be `"bar"`), then you do `$("#elm").data("foo", "update")`, the attribute remains `data-foo="bar"` but the data managed by `data` now has `foo` equal to `"update"`. But the rule above explains it: `data` never *writes* to `data-*` attrs.

Comment: interesting, I had also tried .prop() and it failed as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1143682: That's because attributes aren't properties. :-) It's just that a lot of predefined attributes have reflected properties (`id`, `className`, `rel`, `src`, ...). (`prop` probably *did* create a property on the `div` element, but those aren't serialized when you look at `outerHTML`, because they're not HTML.)

Comment: Ran into this exact same problem; good answer, helped clarify it for me.

Comment: lol wow no wonder jQuery fell off the radar.  Terribly confusing API.  Doing a rewrite on this jQuery application is the pits.  Thanks for the answer, was wondering wth is going on.

Comment: @Spets: While jQuery does absolutely have API issues (and this is one of them), I think a library used by [71.4% of **all** websites globally](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all) can hardly be said to have "fallen off the radar." But if jQuery does start losing share, which I think is likely, I think it won't be down to its API, but rather to MVC/MVVM/choose-your-favorite-acronym-here in the form of React, Angular, Vue, Ember, ...

Comment: wonder how many times I'm going to forget this, and keep coming back and see that I've already up-voted this question\answer.

Comment: @dangel - **LOL** I do that too! There's a particular SQL question... :-)

Answer (score 25):

jQuery imports the `data-` attributes when the element is loaded, but does not access it afterwards. The elements are stored in a jQuery internal structure. From [the API](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> The `data-` attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).