# Failing to set data() using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a jQuery plugin but having some difficulty setting data on an element using jQuery.

I have the code below in an external js file.

```
var imgtd = $('<td></td>');
var img = $('<img src="' + imgdirectory + '16/arrow_up_green.gif" onclick="' +
    'jQuery.multiselectviewer.reOrderMultiSelectViewer(' + index + ', 1, jQuery(this)
    .data(\'multiselectEle\'));" alt="Move ' + controlName + ' up in the list">')
    .data("multiselectEle", i);
$(imgtd).append(img);
var dat = img.data();
$(row).append(imgtd);
```

When I set a breakpoint on the last line, I can see the data assigned to the img element but when I check the element after the page has finished loading the call the data() returns null, and when clicking on the image a null value is passed to the called function.

I imagine it is something simple that I am doing wrong but it has got me stuck.

Answer (score 0):

When setting `data-*` attributes, you should consider using the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function as opposed to [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), as `data()` is better suited for actually reading the values as opposed to writing them as [mentioned in this related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876307/557445):

```
.attr("data-multiselectEle", i);
```

which appears to be [working as expected as seen in the example here](http://jsbin.com/kazibo/edit?html,js,output) :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working, I assume due to it being an object I am trying to assign. It outputs 'data-multiselectele="[object Object]"'. I need to attach the plugins options to the element so they can be accessed from within the called function. I have been looking at another plugin that does something similar and when I call the .data() function in the console on the object generated by that plugin it displays the object properties.

Comment: What is `i` within your context? You might have to use some of the features of the plug-in itself to target the element (and its "data") and then add your updated data to that as it sounds like you don't need a data attribute.