# Set Value to data attribute using jquery for dynamically generated input element

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Created a new input element and tried adding the data attribute using the data method in jquery but am not able to append the value

[Js Fiddle to the above issue](https://jsfiddle.net/bb69fgbj/1/)

```js
var txtBox = $('<input/>', {
  "class": "myCustomClass",
  "type": "text"
});
$('#wrapper').append(txtBox);
txtBox.data('index', '1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>Input Text Box : </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bb69fgbj/3/. The source of your confusion is most likely because `data()` does not update the DOM, so the `data-index` attribute will not appear in the inspector. So long as you use the getter of `data()` to retrieve the value, you will have no issues: `var index = txtBox.data('index')`

Comment: In addition to @RoryMcCrossan's comment, if you want the data to be shown on HTML, you can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

Comment: Used .attr() to overcome the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var txtBox = $('<input/>', {
                "class" : "myCustomClass",
                "type" :"text",
                "data-index":""
            });
$('#wrapper').append(txtBox);           
txtBox.attr('data-index','ddddddddd');
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan is Right. But still if we want to confirm attr is also good option, data is html5 feature.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is working fineI think the code you are looking for is 
`txtBox.attr('data-index', '1');`

for more info why the .data didn't work as you expected , check this answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876274/jquery-data-not-working)

Comment: It is better to add the details from the link into your post in case it ever goes dead.