# Preserve data when converting a jQuery object to html

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an html element which is created in JavaScript.
This element should also save one object as a `data-` attribute and then get converted to pure html.
My problem is that the `data-` attribute vanishes after accessing the `prop("outerHTML")`.

Here is what I mean:

```
let obj = $("<i>TEST</i>");
obj.data("key", "value");
let html = obj.prop("outerHTML");
console.log("DATA: " + obj.data("key")); //gives value
console.log("HTML: " + html); //gives <i>TEST</i>
```

I also tried to directly enter the `data-` attribute, but the quotes a making trouble.

I tried:

```
let dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
let obj = $('<i data-test=' + dataJSON + '</i>'
```

My goal is to generate a dataTable cell which needs to contain some data to handle clicks on it. The whole thing looks like this:

```
columns: [
   data: "notice_id", render: function (data, type, row) {
      let html = $('<i class="edit-button fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>');
      html.data("notice", row);
      return html.prop("outerHTML");
      }]
```

**edit:**
I should have written that I know, that jQuery doesn't really alter the `data-` attribute. I somehow hoped that it would add it anyways when I access the outer html.
However, the linked question doesn't really give an answer on how to make it better (except writing it directly which causes problems with other than simple string data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery .data() not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876274/jquery-data-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback if you want more post processing, and enrich the `<i>` with `data()` in there:

```
columns: [{
  data: "notice_id", 
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    //no need for constructing jQuery instances here
    return '<i class="edit-button fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>'
  },
  createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
    $('i', td).data('notice', rowData)
  }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks man! You helped me even more, because I also found the "`createdRow`" callback which helped me to reduce my code even more.